# How do I deserialize my JSON?

Tags: c#, restsharp

What would be my next step to take? I want to be able to write the block with the id value of ex 1. Or the block with ex GPIO value 3 with something simple as maybe WriteLine(id1) 
Relay.cs

```
public class Relay
{
    public int GPIO { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.0.3:1337/auto/api/v1.0/");
        var request = new RestRequest("relays", Method.GET);  
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

        var response = client.Execute<Relay>(request);

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

and my array on 192.168.0.3:1337/auto/api/v1.0/relays

```
{
 "relays": [
  {
   "GPIO": 2, 
   "id": 1, 
   "status": 0, 
   "type": "Relay"
  }, 
  {
   "GPIO": 3, 
   "id": 2, 
   "status": 0, 
   "type": "Relay"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm sorry if anything is unclear, or if the answer is simple. If I missed to include something important, just point it out and I'll post it!

Comment: Please give this question a meaningful name. "What do I do next?" is not a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse that JSON into objects to manipulate them, and it seems that your REST client already does it, just need to pass the correct type.

1-Create the class structure like the structure you're receiving:

```
    public class Relay
    {
        public int GPIO { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelayCollection
    {

        public Relay[] relays { get; set; }

    }
```

2-Parse the received json:

```
var relayCollection = client.Execute<RelayCollection>(request);
```

Now you have all the relays inside relayCollection.relays, manipulate them as any other array/class

Comment: And how should I declare result? I've tried a few things but none worked.

Comment: 1-if it worked accept the answer. 2-There's no info about "result" in your question, create a new question

Comment: What i ment was, the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RelayCollection>(result)` I get an error saying that 'result' don't exists. So I tried to `string result` witch didn't. So what I mean is what should result be? I asked here since your code example didn't work.

Comment: Ok, forget some things I said, i did a wrong read, you don't need a deserializer, it seems your REST client is already deserializing, read my new answer

Answer (score 0):

you can deserialize it in List of Relay and iterate and read any value you want

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.0.3:1337/auto/api/v1.0/");
        var request = new RestRequest("relays", Method.GET);  
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

        var response = client.Execute<Relay>(request);
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          var relayList = ser.Deserialize<List<Relay>>(response.Content);
         foreach(Relay relay in relayList) 
        Console.WriteLine(relay.ID);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This don't seem to work as nothing gets printed on `Console.WriteLine(relay.id)`nor if i change it to `Console.WriteLine(relay.GPIO)` but no errors are being thrown

Answer (score 0):

Beforehand I apologize for my English, but you can serialize a json by creating a list of your class and then deserialize the json like this:

```
public class Relay {
int GPIO;
public int gPIO {get {return GPIO;} set {GPIO=value;}}
int Id;
public int ID {get {return Id;} set {Id = value;}}
int Status;
public int status {get {return Status;} set {Status = value;}}
string Type;
public string  type {get {return Type;} set {Type = value;}}
}
```

Now create a class list

```
List<Relay > relayList = new List<Relay >();
```

And finally deserealize the json

```
relayList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Relay>>(request);
```